# How to extract a character from a string?

Tags: r, string, function

is there any other function to extract just the nth element of a string besides substr?

```
str="abc"
str[3] #does not work when i want to extract c using index 3
```

Answer (score 1):

There's `stringr::str_sub`

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(str, 3)
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also this can help:

```
strsplit("abc",split='')[[1]][3]

[1] "c"
```

Comment: there is nothing simple like a vector with square brackets? if so, then r is inefficient for strings...

Comment: @Isabelle There are many ways, the simplest is `substring()` as you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach

```
library(stringr)
str="abc"
extracion_string <- str_extract(str, regex("c"))
#[1] "c"
```